# Ignore blocks in parenthesis in regular expression

Tags: c#, regex

I need to retrieve substrings not inside parentheses.

For example, I want to find all **e** characters.

Expected result is marked as strong:

> appl**e**(apple)appl**e**
>
> abcd**e**fg(abeeee)(ae)abc**eee**pp

Comment: This is messy with regular expressions. Consider something like `Regex.Replace(str, @"\(.*?\)", "^").Split('^')` as a possible alternative solution. Won't work with nested parenthesis (which are another issue).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can achieve it with variable-width look-arounds:

```
(?<!\([^()]*)e(?![^()]*\))
```

The `(?<!\([^()]*)` look-behind checks if there is no `(...` before `e` and `(?![^()]*\))` look-ahead checks if there is no `...)` after `e`.

See [demo](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=(%3f%3c!%5c(%5b%5e()%5d*)e(%3f!%5b%5e()%5d*%5c))&i=abcdefg(abeeee)(ae)abceeepp)

[image]

[image]

Comment: result is correct, but I can't include 'appl' in pattern, because it's just for example.

Comment: It's hideous to read (as all useful regexes seem to be :) but it's a really nice solution.